# Will Apple reject this solution for getting unique id in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I want to know if Apple will reject this solution or not for getting the unique id in Xamarin iOS?

```
public string GetIdentifier()
{
    enter code here`var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
    query.Service = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleIdentifier;
    query.Account = "UniqueID";

    NSData uniqueId = SecKeyChain.QueryAsData(query);
    if (uniqueId == null)
    {
        query.ValueData = NSData.FromString(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var err = SecKeyChain.Add(query);
        if (err != SecStatusCode.Success && err != SecStatusCode.DuplicateItem)
            throw new Exception("Cannot store Unique ID");
        return query.ValueData.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return uniqueId.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will Apple reject this solution for getting unique id in Xamarin iOS?

Apple may reject apps that uses private framework/api .

However ,the related framework you used in the code is [Security](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security?language=objc) , it is public .

So , the answer is : No .